# Spatial Clustering and ID Assignment for Roadside Pipes - ArcMap

Tags: arcmap

I have a group of pipes and IDs based on how they were surveyed, like this:

[image]

What I need to do is to group them and create new IDs based on their location, following the logic for example that some of them are on one side of the road and some on the other side.

The expected output should be like this:

[image]

**My idea would be to group the pipes that share similar bearing and also are in contact.
But I'm sure there's a better solution for this.**

Edit:

- This is a small sample but data is big, thousands of lines.
- I don't need to replace geometries in the original layer, output can be a new layer, or even just a column with a Group ID.

Comment: If they are parallel how can they be in contact? Which side, for example, is the left side of the road? How many lines are you taking about, millions? Are you wanting to group into a new feature class or replace geometries in situ? How do you want to deal with junctions? You need to add this information to your question and not as reply to my comment. Edit your question, provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will add more details.